# Riemann Curvature Tensor Vector Fields - What Vector Fields Do I Use?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

$R(X,Y)Z= \nabla_X \nabla_Y Z− \nabla_Y \nabla_XZ−\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$

I am trying to teach myself how to use the Riemann Curvature Tensor. My question is, how do I determine what vector fields to use on the manifold to determine its curvature? My guess would be tangent, normal and binormal vector fields but I am not sure. I've seen basis vectors used, but I don't know what to do in $N$ dimensions. I am trying to make sense of the above equation, the version with the Christoffel symbols is easier for me to understand, but I still don't know what vector fields associated with the manifold to use to find its curvature tensor. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The one you've written reduces to the one with the Christoffel's symbols once you take $X,Y$ and $Z$ to be the coordinate vectors $\partial_i $.

Comment: By the way, the tensor is already found, since you've already got an expression for it. What you might want to find is the coordinates or components with respect to some basis.

Comment: @Dog_69 Do you mean the derivatives of the coordinate vectors or just the coordinate vectors themselves? I'm not sure because of the symbol looking like a partial derivative.

Comment: Let's say $M$ is an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold.  At each point $p \in M$, its tangent space $T_pM$ will be an $n$-dimensional vector space.  In the formula for $R(X,Y)Z$, the objects $X,Y,Z$ are tangent vectors, i.e., elements of a tangent space at some point $p \in M$.  In applications, tangent vectors are often expressed in terms of a basis of $T_pM$ called a "frame."  Anyway, the curvature tensor $R$ is essentially a function that inputs a point $p \in M$ and three tangent vectors $X,Y,Z \in T_pM$, and outputs the vector $\nabla_X\nabla_YZ - \nabla_Y\nabla_XZ - \nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$.

Comment: If you have local coordinates $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ on $M$, then the corresponding coordinate vector fields -- often written $\partial_1, \ldots, \partial_n$ -- give a local frame.  So, you could plug $X = \partial_i$, $Y = \partial_j$, and $Z = \partial_k$ into $R(X,Y)Z = R(\partial_i, \partial_y)\partial_k$.  The result will be a vector, which in coordinates is often written $R_{ijk}^\ell \partial_\ell$.  That is, the components of the tensor $R$ with respect to the coordinate frame are $R^\ell_{ijk}$.  Strictly speaking, $R^\ell_{ijk}$ is not the tensor, but rather its components.

Comment: @JamesShelton Okay, my fault. I mean the coordinate vectors $$\partial_i\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}.$$

Comment: Thanks guys this clears it up. Thanks for all the help and quick responses.